# Date conversions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have a text field from which the date is read like so:

```
var varStartDate = new Date($("#txtFromDate").val());
```

The value in varStartDate comes in mm/dd/yyyy like so:

```
4/7/2014
```

Is there a way to convert this to yyyy/mm/dd so it comes in like so:

```
2014/4/7
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the string and pass the parts to `new Date`

```
var dateArr = $("#txtFromDate").val().split('/');
var StartDate = new Date(dateArr[2], dateArr[0], dateArr[1]);
```

or put them back together again as a string

```
var StartDate = dateArr[2] + '/' + dateArr[0] + '/' + dateArr[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
function getDateInFormat(myDate){
   return myDate.getFullYear()+"/"+("0" + (myDate.getMonth()+1)).substr(-2) +"/"+ myDate.getDate());
}
```

[Here is Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Q3drw/5/)